# How do I get data from a radio/checkbox form submission in the Blazor @code block?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am making a quiz/exam page that uses a Question component. The questions contain answers with either a checkbox or radio selection and a submit button. I need to be able to compare the *selected* answer(s) to the correct answer *when a user clicks submit* (or some other button type), but I am not sure how to get the value of the input inside of my @code block for processing.

I've messed around with @bind-value but it doesn't seem to relate to the button click at all and I only want the value from one answer, the selected one.

So far using a "submit" button doesn't seem to be the right route because it does a POST request, which is not the behavior I'm looking for. I just want the button to trigger processing in the component.

Here is my component

```
<form>
    <div class="q-card">
        <h3>@Question.QuestionText</h3>
        @foreach (var option in Question.Options)
        {
            <div>
                <input type="@Question.InputType" id="@answer" name="@Question.Id" value="@answer"/>
                <label for="@answer">@answer</label>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="q-controls">
            <button type="submit"@onsubmit="@OnSubmit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my @code block

```
@code {
    public string answer;

    public void OnSubmit()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(answer);
    }
}
```

I want the value from the selection to end up in the variable `answer` when I click Submit. I realize if there are multiple answers (checkbox) I'll need to change this variable, but I'll get to that later.

Comment: When a HTML button is clicked, a postback happens. The postback contains the Formular state as well as the button that was pressed. After rebuilding the local copy and filling in the state, the Buttons "OnClick" handler is called. From there it is just accessing any UI element. | I found this overview of the ASP.Net page lifecycle very usefull: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140) It tells you of the basic automagic happening.

Comment: @Christopher: that has nothing to do with how Blazor works, unless I missed something?

Comment: @CollinBrittain: Have you looked at how the Blazor Counter example works?

Comment: @SamAxe That you use some JavaScript or similar mechanism for a partial reload does not really change the basic rules of webpage processing. Those are still what they were when HTML was first defined 1980.

Comment: @SamAxe The counter is different from what I'm trying to do. I know how to update the component with data from my `@code` block but I want to get data from the component _into_ my `@code` block from an input in a form.

Comment: @Christopher that's a really helpful page thank you. Not sure if it specifically answers my question but I needed a resource for all of those events. I appreciate it.

Comment: @CollinBrittain: beware.  Those life-cycle events only apply to WebForms.  If you're doing .net core you are probably doing MVC - which has an entirely different life-cycle.

Comment: @SamAxe this is specifically about Blazor which is client side, so I think all of those events are accessible. EDIT: I mean I've already seen some of those events in Blazor so I bet most of them are usable.

Comment: https://learn-blazor.com/pages/data-binding/

Comment: @CollinBrittain: Blazor *can be* client side.  It can *also* be server side.

Comment: @CollinBrittain As I understand it, the purpose of Blazor is to run C# code - translated to JavaScript - on the client Side using WebAssembly. So it replaces coding in JavaScript with coding in C#, but does not really replace JavaScript.

Comment: What I need is conditional data-binding based on what input is selected in a form, not just general data-binding. Does that make sense? Notice my code has each input spawned with a foreach loop. They can't all get bound to the same variable; I need only one of them to pass data to the answers variable.

Comment: It seems not supported radio buttons two way binding yet and the workaround is like enet has shown.Refer to [here](https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/workaround-how-to-two-way-data-binding-of-radio-button-input-with-blazor-spa-v050-31fd)

Comment: Thank you @XingZou

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Collin Brittain, understand that no post back should happen in Blazor. The behavior you're looking for is available. When you click a button, no post back occurs...Blazor is an SPA app where communication with the outside world is possible only through Http calls or via SignalR. However, I'd suggest you to use the the Forms Components provided by Blazor. Those components provide a great deal of functionality, including validation.

The following working sample may help you to resolve your issue:

```
<form>
        <p>@question</p>

        @foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Question.Colors)))
        {
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="question1" id="@item" value="@item" @onchange="SelectionChanged" checked=@(selectedAnswer.Equals(item,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) />
                <label for="@item">@item</label>
            </div>
        }
        <div>
            <label>Selected answer is @selectedAnswer</label>
        </div>

        <button type="button" @onclick="@OnSubmit">Submit</button>


    </form>




@code {
    string selectedAnswer = "";
    void SelectionChanged(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        selectedAnswer = args.Value.ToString();
    }


    Question question = new Question { QuestionText = "What is the color of the sky" };


    public void OnSubmit()
    { 

          Console.WriteLine(selectedAnswer);

    }

    public class Question
    {

        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public enum Colors { Red, Green, Blue, Yellow };

    }
}
```

**Response to a comment:**

This quote is from the Blazor team:

> Currently we don't call preventDefault by default on DOM events in
>   most cases.
>        The one exception is for form submit events: in that case, if you have a C# onsubmit handler, you almost certainly don't really want to
>   perform a server-side post, especially given that it would occur
>   before an async event handler.
>
> ```
>  Later, it's likely that we'll add a syntax for controlling whether any given event handler triggers a synchronous preventDefault
> ```
>
> before the event handler runs.

In the following code snippet the form has onsubmit handler, the result of which is that navigation to the about page is prevented, you are on the page where the form resides, and the HandleClick event handler for the button is executed:

```
<form action="about:blank" @onsubmit=@(() => { })>
    <button id="form-1-button" @onclick=HandleClick>Click me</button>
</form>
```

This code snippet, however, causes the app to navigate to the about page. In other words, the form is submitted. This behavior means that using the button element without assigning the type property is equivalent to using button with type="submit"

```
<form action="about:blank">
    <button id="form-2-button" @onclick="HandleClick">Click me</button>
</form>
```

In order to prevent navigation to the about page, and execute the HandleClick event handler add the type attribute with the value "button" as done below:

```
<form action="about:blank">
    <button type="button" @onclick="HandleClick" id="form-2-button">Click me</button>
</form>
```

This code snippet from your question

```
<button type="submit"@onsubmit="@OnSubmit">Submit</button>
```

does the following: submit the form instead of calling the OnSubmit event handler of the button element.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'll try this out tomorrow, it looks like what I need thank you! I'll mark the answer when I test. Also on the POST thing, I did read that POSTs should not happen but I noticed if I have a button of type "submit" the page refreshes when I click it which makes me think some type of request is occurring. Maybe that was a bad assumption though.

Comment: Using an expression to set the checked attribute + setting a variable to the current selection is what I was missing. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks again. It can be hard to get quick answers to more specific Blazor questions since it's so new. I'm usually lurking StackOverflow, not posting..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I came up with to implement a radio button group.

```
<EditForm Model="cleaningModel" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
     <DataAnnotationsValidator />
     <div class="form-group">
        <p class="csCleanedBox">
           Cleaned:
        </p>
        <p class="csLineCondition">
            Line Condition:  <br />
            <input type="radio" id="0" name="Cleaned" value="0" checked="checked" @onclick="(() => { RadioButtonClicked(0); })">
            <label for="0">Not Cleaned</label>
        </p>
        <input type="radio" id="1" name="Cleaned" value="1" @onclick="(() => { RadioButtonClicked(1); })">
        <label for="1">1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="2" name="Cleaned" value="2" @onclick="(() => { RadioButtonClicked(2); })">
        <label for="2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="3" name="Cleaned" value="3" @onclick="(() => { RadioButtonClicked(3); })">
        <label for="3">3</label>
        <input type="radio" id="4" name="Cleaned" value="4" @onclick="(() => { RadioButtonClicked(4); })">
        <label for="4">4</label>
        <input type="radio" id="5" name="Cleaned" value="5" @onclick="(() => { RadioButtonClicked(5); })">
        <label for="5">5</label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" @onclick="@BackButton">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <ValidationSummary />
</EditForm>
@Code
{
  public class CleaningDto
  {
    public int Oid { get; set; }
    public int Cleaned { get; set; }
  }
  private readonly CleaningDto cleaningModel = new CleaningDto();
  public void RadioButtonClicked(int value)
  {
    cleaningModel.Cleaned = value;
  }
  private void Submit()
  {
    dm.Save(cleaningModel);
  }
}
```

It works like a radio button group should and the class is updated as the user click on a button.

Comment: This code assumes the user is using a mouse and does not account for the many other ways to change a radio button's state.